# Why is the Orbital Velocity after SECO of Crew Dragon with 27K km/h lower than of ISS?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, dragon-v2

Crew Dragon after SECO: Orbital Vfelocity at 27,000km/h at 200km altitude (roughly 9-10min after liftoff).[image: crewdragon]

ISS Orbital Velocity at ca. 28,000 km/h at 400km altitude.[iss_altitude](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/how-often-does-iss-require-re-boosting-to-higher-orbit),[iss speed](https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/1288920/international-space-station-speed-mph-how-fast-does-iss-travel)

However from the equation $v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}r}$, I expect Crew Dragon to actually rotate faster than the ISS around earth?! What is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: sources for you figures? Most likely a non-circular orbit, with further orbital rendezvous manoeuvrers to follow.

Comment: 1) If your source was the video, that might still be ground speed relative to the rotating Earth's surface, after all, it starts at zero, not 465 $\sin(lat)$ m/s right? 2) The [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) is $$v=\sqrt{GM \left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a} \right)}$$ which works for elliptical orbits (and I think hyperbolic ones as well if you are careful). Your equation is for circular. Use the complete equation and solve for $a$ and you may discover that Crew Dragon was in an elliptical orbit that will carry it to or past the ISS' altitude. It's just a guess

Comment: Min/Max apogee 197km/202km (source: Commentator Crew Demo in Livestream Youtube Video) that orbit is elliptical, but always roughly 200km below ISS.

Comment: My current guess is that it only works due to inertia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2nd stage speed - with respect to what? (SpaceX webcast of Orbcomm OG2 deployment)](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13243/2nd-stage-speed-with-respect-to-what-spacex-webcast-of-orbcomm-og2-deploymen). The answer makes it clear that @uhoh is correct: The velocities are Earth-centered Earth-fixed rather than Earth-centered inertial.

Comment: @DavidHammen thanks for finding that, this sounded familliar. Wow five years ago already!

Comment: rats. I nearly changed my comment to "inertial frames"

Comment: Thank u David. It is a Duplicate, but seems with ISS as rendezvou reference a more nice example. Also, I like to request some Youtubers to do a telemetry tutorial!! Still do not understand what exactly is the advantage of showing Earth-Center-Fixed Velocities, other than adding artifical complexity?!  If anyone can give an answer for check-marking, will be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to David Hammen:

The Velocity of Spacex's Livestream telemetry data is described by ECEF coordinates (earth-centered, earth-fixed). [ECEF Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF)

The equation for orbital velocity used above is valid only for ECI coordinates.

ECEF coordinates are used preferrably in Satellite navigation, because it offers precise values without having to choose a specific ellipsoid. [James R. Clynch: Earth Coordinates.PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20140124040027/http://www.gmat.unsw.edu.au/snap/gps/clynch_pdfs/coorddef.pdf)